# Streaming server - different techniques

Tags: video, streaming

I'm in the planning process of a "home made" streaming server. I've got the actual server in place, but not the streaming software.

I want to setup a web interface in which I can select the media files I wish to stream. The media files can have many different formats (mp3, mp4, avi, mkv, ...) so I need to convert these to mp4/flv/ogv in order to stream them to my devices (pc, ipad, android). I want to use JW Player as the front end solution, and I'll probably install apache with the h264 plugin as the backend.

But how should I go about when streaming the files on demand? Should the media files be encoded once, e.g. by a cron job, and then the resulting files would be streamed? Or should I just stream the originals whilst encoding on the fly?

As the streaming server, I've looked a bit at AVserver / ffserver, and I'll probably go with that. Is there any possibilites to stream files on the fly with this server, or do I have to edit the server's configuration everytime I want to add another?

All help arre greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: did you find any solution to your problem? Actually , i am facing a situation similar to yours.

Comment: For the streaming part I use a mixture of `crtmpd` and nginx `mp4 module`. This works fine, as I convert all media files into mp4 using `avconv`/`ffmpeg`